# FlatList renderItem returning undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have a flatList that renders a component with some props, but the renderItem returns me 'undefined'. I´m new to react-native and I cant´t find a solution. Thanks

edit:

Is it possible that the styles I used in 'posts.js' may affect the flatList render?

Feed.js:

```
  export default function Feed() {
    const Posts = [
        { id: 1, title: "eu", photoDesc: 'eu' },
        { id: 2, title: "me", photoDesc: 'me' }

    ]
    console.log;

    return (
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={props => props.id}
            data={Posts}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <FeedPosts title={`${item.title}`} photoDesc={`${item.photoDesc}`} ></FeedPosts>}
        >
        </FlatList>
    );

}
```

Posts.js:

```
 export default function FeedPosts(props) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <FontAwesome5 name='bell' size={40} style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}></FontAwesome5>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Ionicons name='add-circle' size={40} style={{ marginRight: 5 }}></Ionicons>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Header>
            <Body>
                <Time>15/12/2021 as 17:42pm</Time>
                <User>
                    <Icon source={require('../../assets/vibe.jpg')}></Icon>
                    <Description>{props.title}</Description>
                </User>

                <Content>
                    <PetPhoto source={props.postImg}></PetPhoto>
                </Content>

                <ContentDesc >
                    <PhotoDesc> {props.photoDesc}</PhotoDesc>
                </ContentDesc>

                <Bottom>
                    <Comment title="Comment" placeholder="Escrever Comentário"></Comment>
                </Bottom>
                <Buttons></Buttons>
            </Body>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `Posts` contains an array of React components. Instead, it should contain an array of data that you transform into components.

So your `Posts` should look more like this:

```
const Posts = [
 {title: "My title", photoDesc: "Desc"},
 {title: "My title2", photoDesc: "Desc2"},
 {title: "My title3", photoDesc: "Desc3"}
]
```

Here's an example (straight from the React Native documentation) of how this works in context:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

(https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

You can see in the above example that `DATA` is an array of objects, which gets transformed with the function `renderItem` into components. Very similar to your use case.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But it only renders one component, even if ´Posts` has more than one data

Comment: That shouldn't happen. If you edit your question your question with code (not screenshots) I can take a look.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. The 'container' is a styled view component, i just add 'flex: 1' for it and it rendered both screens, thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing. In props, postImg is an image, how can I get it from the array of datas?

Comment: If they're local images, you can pass them through require (postImg: require('imgSrc')). If you're loading them from somewhere else, I'd suggest you keep the URL in the data array and then load the image in your child component.